# How do you sort multiple types in ruby?

Tags: ruby, sorting

Suppose you have an array of runners:

```
runners = [al, betty, chris, debby]
```

And you have a method `time` that returns the runner's time in the race.

In the case that the `time` method always returns a float, I know that you can sort the runners by there times using `sort_by` as follows:

```
runners.sort_by do |runner|
    runner.time
end
```

However, suppose that `time` sometimes returned a string, say `"disqualified"`. In that case, how would you sort the runners by time, with the disqualified runners last? What if you wanted the disqualified runners first or in some other position?

Comment: I'd encourage you to not overload your expected time value with a string. Instead, use a separate `is_disqualified?` `true`/`false` attribute and let the time value always be a float, or better, a Time object. The logic can get very convoluted when we use unexpected types, which will take its toll farther down the road when you have to revisit the code and relearn why you did things a certain way.

Comment: @the Tin Man: This isn't Java, the function name should be `disqualified?`, not `is_disqualified?`. :-)

Comment: Actually, I was thinking in ActiveRecord terms.

Comment: @the Tin Man: I don't think ActiveRecord has a precedent for using `is_` in front of boolean getters, either.

Comment: I'm voting to disqualify this question as a possible duplicate of [Sort a collection of objects by number (highest first) then by letter (alphabetical)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232470/sort-a-collection-of-objects-by-number-highest-first-then-by-letter-alphabetic) (also sporting-themed!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple way. Just have two sort fields in an array, and Ruby will sort by the first criterion and then the second.

```
runners.sort_by do |runner|
    [(runner.time == 'disqualified') ? 1 : 0, runner.time]
end
```

Here `1` will be sorted after `0`, so disqualified times will come last.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom class for this:

```
class RunningTime
  attr_reader :time

  def initialize time
    @time = time
  end

  def disqualified?
    @time == 'disqualified'
  end

  def <=> rhs
    case [disqualified?, rhs.disqualified?]
    when [false, true]
      -1
    when [true, true]
      0
    when [true, false]
      1
    else
      time <=> rhs.time
    end
  end
end

runners.sort_by {|runner| RunningTime.new(runner.time)}
```

Comment: I'm going to have to do a little studying in order to understand this class. Thanks for helping me learn something!

Comment: @Michael: You should, like, totally forget my answer and just go with Peter's. :-P It has more or less a similar idea to my answer, only 10x simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Is time returning `Object.time.to_f`? If so, calling to_f on a String will return 0.0. If not, try calling runner.time.to_f in the block. All time values of type String will be 0.0.

Comment: The problem with that is that 0 is a valid running time value, and should not be treated the same as disqualified. (The more general variant of the problem is a case where `disqualified` cannot map onto _any_ valid number value (including infinity), and must be treated specially. That's what my answer addresses.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it analogous to this:

```
[5,4,"disqualified",2,7].sort_by { |x| x.kind_of?(String) ? Float::INFINITY : x } 
#=> [2, 4, 5, 7, "disqualified"]
```

In Ruby < 1.9 there is no `Float::INFINITY`, but you can get it by doing `Inf = 1.0 / 0`.

Comment: @Michael Hoffman: `Float::INFINITY` is a constant representing, well, an infinitely large floating point number. IOW: a disqualified runner will simply be compared as if he had ran infinitely slow.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Thanks for this explanation. So `Float` refers to the float class, and `INFINITY` is a class constant for that class?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're runners come from a database, using a separate field / method for checking for disqualified runners lets you push the sorting logic into the database layer, which will be faster than loading all of the records into memory & sorting them in ruby.

Comment: For the actual problem I was facing I have gone with the solution (that I think is) what you're describing. I removed the items that had non-numeric values, sorted the ones that did, and then tacked on the removed items in a separate process.