# Sorting Pair with second value in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to sort the list according to second value of a pair, this is my code for class Pair and make_pair :

```
    class Pair

      attr_accessor :first,:second

    end

    def make_pair(x,y)
      temp = Pair.new

      temp.first = x
      temp.second = y

      return temp
    end

    arr = []

    arr.push(make_pair("abc",make_pair("def",2)))
    arr.push(make_pair("abc",make_pair("def",3)))
    arr.push(make_pair("abc",make_pair("def",1)))
    arr.push(make_pair("abc",make_pair("def",4)))

    arr.sort {|a,b| a.second.second <=> b.second.second}

    print(arr[0].second.second)
```

I saw this [Sorting a two-dimensional array by second value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033719/sorting-a-two-dimensional-array-by-second-value) and tried but list remains the same, how to correctly do it? I want to sort it by arr.second.second i.e the integer value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `#sort` does not modify the original array. It returns a new one with elements sorted: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort

You just need to assign sorted result to a variable:

`arr = arr.sort {|a,b| a.second.second <=> b.second.second}`

#### Style comments

That said, even though it's not asked in the question, you could make this code cleaner by removing `make_pair` method and putting it's contents into `Pair#initialize`:

```
class Pair
  attr_reader :first, :second

  def initialize(first, second)
    @first = first
    @second = second
  end
end
```

I feel like sort is unnecessarily verbose for this scenario and [`#sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) would fit better:

`sorted = arr.sort_by{ |item| item.second.second  }`

Comment: _"You just need to assign sorted result to a variable"_ – or use `sort!` / `sort_by!` to modify the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily perform this task as:

```
arr.sort_by! { |x| x.second.second }
```

If you don't want to change the original array, remove the `!` from method signature and save the result to another variable:

```
new_arr = arr.sort_by { |x| x.second.second }
```