# Sorting a two-dimensional array with more than one criterion

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

What would be the simplest ruby code to sort this table so that on the first column it
is sorted in ascending order, while in the second column it is sorted in descending order

```
matrix = [ [1,1],
           [2,1],
           [2,4],
           [2,3],
           [2,2],
           [3,1],
           [4,2],
           [4,3],
           [4,4],
           [1,4],
           [1,3],
           [1,2],
           [3,2],
           [3,4],
           [3,3],
           [4,1] ]
```

Resulting table should be:

```
[[1,4],
 [1,3],
 [1,2],
 [1,1],
 [2,4],
 [2,3],
 [2,2],
 [2,1],
 [3,4],
 [3,3],
 [3,2],
 [3,1],
 [4,4],
 [4,3],
 [4,2],
 [4,1] ]
```

Any help appreciated,
Ted

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a collection of objects by number (highest first) then by letter (alphabetical)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232470/sort-a-collection-of-objects-by-number-highest-first-then-by-letter-alphabetic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
matrix.sort_by {|e| [e[0], -e[1]]}
```

I think that's the simplest but according to the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001481), it can be quite expensive when the keysets are simple.

Comment: expand the block arguments: matrix.sort_by { |x, y| [x, -y] }